# Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version xCode 4.3

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3, ios5.1, application-loader

I saw this error I other posts but the most of them have a beta version of Xcode. is my Xcode **Version 4.3 (4E71d) with sdk 5.1** a beta version? or just Apple wants me to update my Xcode. I remember that I could upload other apps since a year ago so I think that the problem is the version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a beta version but it is old. The current version of Xcode is 4.6 and iOS 6.1.x. Apple tend to expect you to be using recent versions.

Comment: ok thanks, I wanted to checked it, could I install xcode 4.6 in my Lion?

Comment: @tato469 Yes, Xcode 4.6 runs on Lion - as long as your copy of Lion is up to date.